# php sort after query fired

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, mysqli

I want to sort highest to lowest cip and also lowest to highest cip, but cip value is not stored in database, it is calculated as soon as query is fired. 
Here is html code to select sorting:

```
  <select name="cip">
                    <option>Select CIP percentage</option>
                    <option value="1">Highest To Lowest</option>
                    <option value="2">Lowest To Highest</option>
            </select>
```

And here is the query that I fired!

```
    $select_applicant = "SELECT j.*, u.id, u.gender
                        FROM job_apply j
                        LEFT JOIN users u
                        ON u.id = j.user_id
                        WHERE j.job_id = '".$jid."'";

    $result_applicant = mysqli_query($con, $select_applicant);
    while($row_applicant = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_applicant))
    {
        $user_id = $row_applicant["user_id"];
        $user_info = get_user_profile_info($user_id);
        $ratings_dist = get_skill_ratings_stats($user_id);
                $got_it_total_rating = 0;
                foreach($ratings_dist as $category=>$rating)
                {
                    $got_it_total_rating = $got_it_total_rating + $rating['score'];
                }
                $got_it_total_category = count($ratings_dist);
                $total_cip = ceil($got_it_total_rating / $got_it_total_category);

                echo $total_cip;
    }
```

Function "get_skill_ratings_stats" in php is as below:

```
function get_skill_ratings_stats($user_id){
    global $con;
    $items = array();
    if($user_id>0)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT 
            s.category_id category_id, 
            c.name as category, 
            COALESCE(r.score_quality, 0.0) quality, 
            COALESCE(r.score_timing, 0.0) timing, 
            COALESCE(r.score_budget, 0.0) budget, 
            COALESCE(r.score_resp, 0.0) resp, 
            COALESCE(r.score_pro, 0.0) pro
        FROM `user_skills` s 
        LEFT JOIN `skill_categories` c
        ON c.category_id=s.category_id
        LEFT JOIN `skill_ratings` r
        ON r.skill_id=s.skill_id 
        WHERE s.user_id = '".(int)$user_id."'
        AND s.status = 'active'
        ORDER BY category ASC";
        $prev_cat   = '';
        $result     = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        // die(mysqli_error($con));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
            // print_r($row);
            if(!$row['category']) continue;
            if($row['category']!=$prev_cat)
            {
                if(isset($items[$prev_cat]['score']) && $items[$prev_cat]['score']>0 && count($items[$prev_cat])>1)
                {
                    $items[$prev_cat]['score'] = floor(($items[$prev_cat]['score']*20)/(count($items[$prev_cat])-1));
                }
                $prev_cat = $row['category'];
            }
            if(!isset($items[$prev_cat]['score'])) $items[$prev_cat]['score'] = 0;
            $items[$prev_cat][]             = $row;
            $items[$prev_cat]['score']  += ($row['quality']+$row['timing']+$row['budget']+$row['resp']+$row['pro'])/5;
        }
    }
    // print_r($items);
    // die();
    if(isset($items[$prev_cat]['score']) && $items[$prev_cat]['score']>0 && count($items[$prev_cat])>1)
    {
        $items[$prev_cat]['score'] = floor(($items[$prev_cat]['score']*20)/(count($items[$prev_cat])-1));
    }
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($items as $cat=>$item) {
        $tmp[$item['score'].'-'.$cat] = $item;
    }
    krsort($tmp);
    $items = array();
    foreach($tmp as $k=>$v) {
        $k = preg_replace('#^\d+-#is', '', $k);
        $items[$k] = $v;
    }
    // print_r($tmp);
    // print_r($items);
    // die();
    return $items;
}
```

Please help me! Having hard time with this!

Comment: did you try `usort()`?

Comment: i read about it on php.net, but dont know how to apply it in my case! can you help me with that?

Comment: Did you try to google for "How to use usort"?

Comment: yes, i did, i tried like below link:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_usort
however unsuccessful!

Comment: What exactly have you tried and why didn't you post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [We0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1852803/we0) said,

```
 $total_cips[] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'cip' => ceil($got_it_total_rating / $got_it_total_category));
```

but then i used multisort function:

```
            function multi_sort($array, $akey)
            { 
              function compare($a, $b)
              {
                 global $key;
                 return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
              }
              usort($array, "compare");
              return $array;
            }
```

And then I call the function as below:

```
$total_cips = multi_sort($total_cips, $key = 'cip');
```

Finally this one worked!

Anyways thanks [We0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1852803/we0) & [Ankit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2607359/ankit-pokhrel)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a html table to display this I would just go with http://datatables.net/ , it will give you a lot of sorting options very easily...

Otherwise usort():

```
function cip($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['cip'] == $b['cip']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['cip'] < $b['cip']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$data = array(
   [0] => array('cip' => 1)
   [1] => array('cip' => 5)
   [2] => array('cip' => 2)
);

usort($data, "cip");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Assuming your array looks something like this:

```
array(
   [0] => array('cip' => 1)
   [1] => array('cip' => 5)
   [2] => array('cip' => 2)
)
```

It basically loops til everything is sorted, all you do in the call back function is tell it which values to compare...

EDIT:

```
$total_cips[] = array('user_id' => $user_id, 'cip' => ceil($got_it_total_rating / $got_it_total_category));
```

Ok So now you have all the total cips in an array with there user_id right?

And outside for loop you call `usort($total_cips, "cip");`

Then you have a sorted array, if you wish to change the sorting direction just change the `greater than` to a `less than` in the cip function

Comment: how do i get all total_cip values from query into an array?

Comment: Well I thought your work that out in the `get_skill_ratings_stats` function? I figure you are getting data and then you want to sort it? I might be totally missing something, but that data come back in an array and you would `usort()` that array?

Comment: after some calculations, i get total_cip in while as you can see! so i want to sort total_cip value.... but question is how do i gather all total_cip values from while loop and then sort it with usort...

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
 $select_applicant = "SELECT j.*, u.id, u.gender
                        FROM job_apply j
                        LEFT JOIN users u
                        ON u.id = j.user_id
                        WHERE j.job_id = '".$jid."";
```

You are missing `closing quote` for `$jid`. It should be:

```
 $select_applicant = "SELECT j.*, u.id, u.gender
                        FROM job_apply j
                        LEFT JOIN users u
                        ON u.id = j.user_id
                        WHERE j.job_id = '".$jid."'";
```

This might be one of the cause of your problem.

Comment: i am already getting results... that is not the issue.... i just want it to be sort... thanks for looking!

Comment: I wonder how you get your result :o. Missing quote must be a syntax error. I just checked through phpmyadmin :D. I don't think there is a reason to downvote my answer (for the one who downvoted).